# Summation of fractions of Gamma functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function

Recently I gave Mathematica the following input on the left hand side

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(a+n)}{\Gamma(b+n)}=\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b-a-1)}{\Gamma(b-1)\Gamma(b-a)}.
$$

Can anyone explain to me what identities are needed to get the expression on the right hand side above?

Comment: What have you already tried? Try adding your thoughts to the question in order to get the most appropriate answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definition and properties of the Beta function:
$$ \frac{\Gamma(a+n)}{\Gamma(b+n)}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(b-a)}B(a+n,b-a) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(b-a)}\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)^{b-a-1}x^{a+n-1}\,dx. $$
If you sum both sides on $n\geq 0$, you end up with:

$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\Gamma(a+n)}{\Gamma(b+n)}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(b-a)}\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)^{b-a-2}x^{a-1}\,dx=\frac{B(a,b-a-1)}{\Gamma(b-a)}=\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b-a-1)}{\Gamma(b-1)\Gamma(b-a)}. $$

Comment: Wow, that was pretty fast. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

With [Hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Special_values_at_z_=_1)
\begin{align}
\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b-a-1)}{\Gamma(b-1)\Gamma(b-a)} 
&=\frac{\Gamma(a)}{\Gamma(b)}{}_2F_1(1,a,b;1)\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(a)}{\Gamma(b)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1)_n(a)_n}{(b)_nn!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1)_n}{n!}\frac{\Gamma(a)(a)_n}{\Gamma(b)(b)_n}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(a+n)}{\Gamma(b+n)}
\end{align}